# Pass exception to the application

Tags: windbg

In Immunity Debugger you would use <kbd>Shift+F7</kbd> to pass the exception to the app. How do I do this in Windbg? Pressing `g` does not do anything.  It only repeats the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WinDbg you have additional choice of

`gh` (Go with Exception Handled) or `gn` (Go with Exception Not Handled)

It also distinguishes between first chance and second chance exceptions.
On first chance, pressing `g` or `gn` will  pass the exception to to the program.
If the program doesn’t handle, there will be a second chance, which looks nearly the same in WinDbg.

```
(3480.1bf0): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.

CrashTest!CCrashTestDlg::OnButtonCrash+0x15:
00000001`400083f5 c70005000000    mov     dword ptr [rax],5         ds:00000000`00000000=????????
0:000> g
(3480.1bf0): Access violation - code c0000005 (!!! second chance !!!)
CrashTest!CCrashTestDlg::OnButtonCrash+0x15:
00000001`400083f5 c70005000000    mov     dword ptr [rax],5     ds:00000000`00000000=????????
```

More info: [Controlling Exceptions and Events (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539287(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you. My program does not show the default Windows error box when I pass the exception to the program, however, when it should crash.